# Crash with omniture analytics/adobe-analytics when debugging the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, adobe-analytics

I am pretty new to Omniture stuff here and I was working with it when integrating that feature of tracking stuff on my Android application.

So basically, I have finished working with my application and now I was thinking of implementing some Analytics stuff in my code.

I tried to use omniture in couple of places in my application and my application doesn't doesn't crash unless I am doing some debugging session.

So my app has a simple structure, it was a splash screen followed by couple of fragments. Now, according to omniture framework, there are multiple ways we can either collect analytics data but I am specifically using it for an **analyticState** or **analyticAction**. I am using analyicState when the the view actually comes in the onResume state or onFragmentResumed state and analyticAction when any clickAction has happened. 
The crash happens in one of the fragments and that fragment is wrapped within an activity.

**Now, only while debugging the application, I got these crashes and I am assuming its because of the null pointer object.**

**First error logs for the crash:**

```
04-22 16:32:46.068  30549-30604/somepackagename E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
    Process: somepackagename, PID: 30549
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.adobe.mobile.RequestBuilder.buildAndSendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:95)
            at com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsTrackState.trackState(AnalyticsTrackState.java:31)
            at com.adobe.mobile.Analytics$1.run(Analytics.java:63)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
```

**Second error log :**

```
04-22 16:35:29.372    32329-511/somepackagename E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-41846
    Process: somepackagename, PID: 32329
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsWorker$Hit.identifier' on a null object reference
            at com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsWorker$WorkerThreadRunner.run(AnalyticsWorker.java:313)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
```

**Note :** These crashes only **occur when debugging** the application and not when normally using the application.

Will like to track down the issue and any help will be really appreciated. This can help future viewers too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also getting similar issue with adobe-analytics. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Shubham Didn't get a solution for that issue yet .. :(